# How to Let CMD Know a Batch Script Failed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is `example.bat`:

```
@echo ERROR
@exit /b 1
```

In `cmd.exe`, execute this:

```
example.bat && (echo successful!) || echo failed!
```

Got:

```
ERROR
successful!
```

Is there a way to let cmd know `example.bat` failed and therefore print below output?

```
ERROR
failed!
```

Comment: Why not simply `cmd /C example.bat && echo successful! || echo failed!` ?

Comment: As you're already using an exit code, you should be using it when determining the message to print. For example: `Call "example.bat"`, `If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo failed.) Else Echo successful.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug/side effect of cmd.exe, if a batch file is started without `call` or `cmd /c`.

These variations work as expected

```
call example.bat && echo successful! || echo failed!
cmd /c example.bat && echo successful! || echo failed!
```